# $\sup \sum a_i \ln(b_i)$ with $\sum a_i = \sum b_i =1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I was faced with the following problem: I need to know where the $\sup \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \ln(b_i)$ is taken if $0 < a_i, b_i < 1$ subject to the constraint $\sum a_i = \sum b_i =1$. I'm not so much interested in the actual value of the $\sup$, just on what $n-$tuple $(a_i)$ with $(b_i)$ being fixed it is taken. Hopefully the answer will be $a_i = b_i$. This problem arose when I was trying to compute a topological pressure of some dynamical system and $a_i, b_j$ are measures of some sets, but I need this strictly algebraic inequality and I can't figure how to prove it.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange Multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given $\{b_i\}$ it os more or less obvious that the gready approach to let $a_j=1$ for some $j$ with $\ln b_j=\max$ (i.e. $b_j=\max$) and $a_i=0$ otherwise maximizes $\sum a_i\ln b_i$ with a value of $\ln b_j$ and is itself maximized when $b_j=1$. While $0$ and $1$ are expressly forbidden and hence the supremum is not assumed, it is clear that we can get arbitrarily close. Hence the $\sup$ is $0$.

(If several $b_j$ are maximal, letting all "other" $a_i=0$ and those belonging to maximizing indices arbitrary (subject to tha $\sum=1$ constraint, will do the same approximating the supremum)

Comment: of course, right, thanks for the input! unfortunately I've messed up a bit and asked a different question than I meant to, I wanted to show $\sum a_i \ln(b_i) \leq \sum a_i \ln(a_i)$, here's my another try: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611012/sum-a-i-lnb-i-leq-sum-a-i-lna-i-with-sum-a-i-sum-b-i-1