# $\sum a_i \ln(b_i) \leq \sum a_i \ln(a_i)$ with $\sum a_i = \sum b_i = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Okay, this is my another try on the question [$\sup \sum a_i \ln(b_i)$ with $\sum a_i = \sum b_i =1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610918/sup-sum-a-i-lnb-i-with-sum-a-i-sum-b-i-1) which I unfortunately mis-stated and actually asked for a problem different than the one I have to solve. I wish to show that given the constraints $0 < a_i, b_j < 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i = 1$ we have the following inequality:
$$\sum a_i \ln(b_i) \leq \sum a_i \ln(a_i)$$
The problem arose when I was trying to compute some topological pressures and $a_i, b_j$ are actually measures of some sets, but this inequality (if, hopefully, true) is purely algebraic. Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the AM/GM inequality with weights $a_i$,
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n \Big(\frac{b_i}{a_i}\Big)^{a_i}
  \le \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \Big(\frac{b_i}{a_i}\Big) = 1 $$
Rearranging yields
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n b_i^{a_i} \le \prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{a_i} $$
and taking logs yields the desired inequality.

Comment: thanks for the input, real nice!

Answer (score 6):

The magic words are "lagrange multipliers". You want to optimize
$$f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)=\sum a_i \log x_i,$$ subject to the constraint $\sum x_i = 1.$

So, you must have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = c,$ for some constant $c,$ so $\frac{a_i}{x_i}= c.$ In other words, the $b_i$ at the optimum are proportional to the $a_i,$ but the sums are the same, so $b_i \equiv a_i.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum a_i\ln(b_i)-\sum a_i\ln(a_i)=\sum a_i\ln \frac{b_i}{a_i}\le\ln\Big(\sum a_i \frac{b_i}{a_i}\Big)=0,$$
by the concavity of the logarithmic function.